# Writing a Partial Sum GPU Kernel

Tags: opencl, gpu

I have the following array with sparse 1's every now and then. Its a massive vector, megabytes in size

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ..]
```

I need to store those 1's at an index for processing, so I need a kernel that produces this:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ..]
```

How can I parallelize such an operation?

Comment: "(parallel) prefix sum" is the term you want to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a 'parallel inclusive scan', which the *thrust* library (ships with the cuda toolkit), includes out of the box:

```
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int data[17] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    thrust::device_vector< int > in( data, data + 17 );
    thrust::device_vector< int > out( in.size() );

    thrust::inclusive_scan( in.begin(), in.end(), out.begin() );

    for ( int i = 0; i < out.size(); ++i )
        std::cout << out[i] << " ";
    std::cout << endl;
}
```

outputs:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
```

Or you could explicitly write a kernel - which will just be a variation on the [parallel prefix sum](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html) algorithm, which thrust generalizes nicely.

Comment: I need it for opencl. Is there a nice function or lib for that

Comment: Yes - there's 'bolt' which is pretty much identical to thrust: https://hsa-libraries.github.io/Bolt/html/group__CL-scan.html

Comment: Oh that is great. I currently have my data as a cl::buffer. Is there a code example out there that demonstrates the use of this api? Particularly the inclusive or exclusive scan functions

Comment: cl::buffer to bolt::cl::device_vector to bolt::cl::inclusive_scan.  See https://hsa-libraries.github.io/Bolt/html/classbolt_1_1cl_1_1device__vector.html#acba05b856ae25b393d0b781cac71599b for the first part.

Comment: the library appears to be dead. it was last updated in 2014

Comment: This stuff doesn't change much - like I said, it's all a variation on well optimized prefix sum implementations.  You might need to do a little foot work to get it working... good luck.